# URL Rewrite with 3 parameters for forum .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to URL Rewrite to the following URL

```
Http://***.com/index.php?p=forum&mod=view_posts&page=$3&name=$2&id=$1

Http://***.com/forum/{id}-{name}/{page}

Http://***.com/forum/1-Hello-World/1
```

I have tryed the following code and have had no joy

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([^-]+)-([^&]+)/([^-]+)$ index.php?p=forum&mod=view_posts&page=$3&orderby=$2&id=$1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regex isn't very good: you see, the "([^&]+)" says: "one or more characters, up until the first ampersand", while you have no ampersands in the subject. Also, the "([^-]+)$" says "one or more characters before a hyphen", while you don't intend to end the subject with a hyphen.

Try this one:

```
^forum/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/(.+)$
```

But note that this actually captures any characters in the id and page positions, so you might be better off with

```
^forum/([0-9]+)-([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$
```

as that allows only numbers in those positions.

Also, you probably meant "index.php?p=forum&mod=view_posts&page=$3&name=$2&id=$1" instead of "index.php?p=forum&mod=view_posts&page=$3&orderby=$2&id=$1"